# How do I know if a user has a blog in Wordpress Multisite?

Tags: multisite

I have a Wordpress Multisite installation with Buddypress. I would want to restrict people from creating another blog so that they have only one blog.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the user meta key `primary_blog`:

```
$user_has_blog = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'primary_blog', TRUE );
```

For users without a blog `$user_has_blog` will be false now. For other users `$user_has_blog` is the blog ID.